# c# development environment(s) for Mac

Tags: xamarin, monodevelop, xamarin-studio, xamarin.mac

I'm a seasoned c# developer on Windows but have recently bought my first Macbook and have decided to do some c# development on Mac.  I've downloaded and installed Xcode, MonoMac and MonoDevelop (Xamarin Studio 5.5.4).  Some of the project templates seem to be missing (mac unified template being one).  Can anyone point me to any resources to get me started with the classic template or instructions on how to get all the templates, or even alternative development environments for c# development on Mac ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned on the website, the unified templates are not include in the stable version yet. So, you need to switch to the alpha channel to have access the the Unified API. Read more about this here: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/updating_mac_apps/

EDIT:

It seems that Xamarin.Mac is only available, if you purchase it. Refere to the link here: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2231/what-do-i-need-to-do-to-install-and-use-xamarin-mac#latest

Comment: Thanks Robin ... I had a sneaky feeling that the Xamarin.Mac template was only available through purchase (Indie licence or above !!!)